# Bristling sound. Does it exist?

Tags: word-usage

Would it be correct to say?:

> She is bristling at her son.

Bristle at(to show anger) is a phrasal verb in which Bristle means a kind of sound. I've never heard of Bristling sound. I know Hissing sound but not this one. So, would it be correct?

Comment: The image is of an animal with bristles, like a porcupine or certain pigs who hair-like structures are raised when bothered. It is not necessarily anger, it can be annoyance or irritation or feeling indignant. Bristle is usually followed by at but it is not a phrasal verb per se. It just takes the preposition at.

Comment: I only want to know whether I can use this statement while expressing my rage on my boyfriend?(I'm now bristling at you, and you aren't listening)

Comment: Normally, it is descriptive: She bristled at what he said. But not: "I'm bristling at you". Mostly not unless you're a poet. :) "You're getting on my nerves."

Comment: If you bristle at your boyfriend, he may call you a sow.  Just sayin' https://www.google.com/search?q=bristling+wild+boar+sow+image&num=20&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=Qkxxnvwgr0ZhtM%253A%252C6iKZXevR7Wh0xM%252C_&usg=__jxnu4xBPAeO6I6Hrty2qyaSSOfA%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv0duutdPaAhXSUt8KHeDoD7UQ9QEIPTAJ#imgrc=Qkxxnvwgr0ZhtM:

Answer (score 1):

To Bristle at something is not to make a sound, but it would be conveyed by a look or change in tone.  Primarily, it occurs internally to the person who is bristling.

Comment: Yes, a change in facial expression or tone.

Answer (score 1):

"Bristle" is a verb, although normally used without a direct object.  The image is of an angry animal making its fur stand up as a defensive reaction:

> "What the hell do you mean by that?" she **bristled**.

Because this is generally a *soundless* action there is no word to describe the sound "bristling" makes -- possibly a "rustle", although this does not imply anger.

However there are various other "angry" verbs that at least *suggest* some sort of sound, related to the image they evoke.  Most of these are related to fire or heat:

> - seethe (like a tightly lidded, boiling pot)
> - steam (like steam escaping from something boiling)
> - simmer (like a liquid on moderate heat, quietly cooking)
> - fume (like a fire producing smoke)
> - boil (like a liquid over high heat)
> - explode (like a violent burst)
> - erupt (like a volcano)

plus a few others

> - spit (like an angry cat or snake)
> - chafe (like two things rubbing against one another)
> - bridle (like an upset horse)